# Finding number of ways so that equal sum can be produced?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So, I am trying to solve [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/466/problem/C) question:

> You've got array a[1], a[2], ..., a[n], consisting of n integers. Count the number of ways to split all the elements of the array into three contiguous parts so that the sum of elements in each part is the same.
>
> Input
>   The first line contains integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 5·10^5), showing how many numbers are in the array. The second line contains n integers a[1], a[2], ..., a[n] (|a[i]| ≤  10^9) — the elements of array a.
>
> Output
>   Print a single integer — the number of ways to split the array into three parts with the same sum. For example,

```
input
5
1 2 3 0 3
output
2
```

My approach was: Take sum of all input numbers. Find if it's divisible by 3 or not. If it's not, directly output 0 and if it is divisible by 3, then we need to count the number of ways. Therefore, what I did was,

Found the values of indexes (ind1, ind2, ind3) where I am able to find the first subarray which satisfy the given condition. That is,

```
int ind1=0,ind2=0,ind3=0;
    while (ind1 < n)
    {
        p = p + arr[ind1];
        if (p != val)
            ind1++;
        else if (p == val)
        {
            f1 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    ind2 = ind1;
    ind2++;
    p = 0;
    while (ind2 < n)
    {
        p = p + arr[ind2];
        if (p != val)
            ind2++;
        else if (p == val)
        {
            f2 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    ind3 = ind2;
    ind3++;
    p = 0;
    while (ind3 < n)
    {
        p = p + arr[ind3];
        if (p != val)
            ind3++;
        else if ( p == val )
        {
            f3 = 1;
            //ans++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

And after I have `ind1, ind2, ind3` I start checking for the presence of 0's because only due to them, we will have more than one way. However, I don't seem to get a correct answer through this on for example,

```
Input: 
9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Correct O/P should be 28 but mine is coming out to be 7. Is my logic wrong?

Edit: As suggested:
    val = sum/3;   // here sum is sum of all numbers
    for ( i = n-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            k = k + arr[i];
            if (k == val)
                backward[i] = 1;
        }
        k = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            k = k + arr[i];
            if ( k == val )
                forward[i] = 1;
        }
        long long int ans = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < n-2; i++ )
        {
            if (forward[i] == 1)
            {
                for ( k = i+2; k < n; k++ ) // i+2 because there should be atleast 
                                               one element in between which act as 
                                               sum/3
                {
                    if (backward[k] == 1)
                        ans++;
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Correct O/P should be 28 but mine is coming out to be 7. Is my logic wrong?

Yes. After you run your code you have the following:

```
   ind1 ind2 ind3
    |    |    |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (1)
```

after you start to search for zeroes  you will find the following configurations

```
   ind1 ind2      ind3
    |    |         |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (2)
   ind1 ind2           ind3
    |    |              |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (3)
   ind1 ind2                ind3
    |    |                   |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (4)
   ind1 ind2                     ind3
    |    |                        |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (5)
   ind1 ind2                          ind3
    |    |                             |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (6)
   ind1 ind2                               ind3
    |    |                                  |
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (7)
```

which are the 7 configurations you find. But this is not what you want. First you need only two indices, not 3, your ind3 should always point to the last element. You need to calculate 3 sums - from to **0** to **ind1-1**,  from to **ind1** to **ind2**, and  from to **ind2+1** to **n-1**. So you need ot have that **ind1 >= 1**, **ind2 >= ind1**, **ind2 < n-1**. So valid configurations are:

```
        ind1
         |
        ind2                           
         |                                 
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (1)

        ind1 ind2
         |    |                               
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (2)
        ind1      ind2
         |         |                               
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (3)
    ...
        ind1                          ind2
         |                             |                               
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (7)
```

And then you should start moving the `ind1` also

```
             ind1
              |
             ind2                           
              |                                 
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         (8)
    ...
```

So the number of configurations you'd get is: 7 + 6 + 5 + ... + 1= 28

Also beware that this algorithm is O(n^2) which would most likely timeout due to the fact that **n** can reach up to 10^5. So, in order, to pass all test you should use different approach. What you could do is the following. First calculate the sets of array indices A = {i | a[0]+a[1]+..+a[i-1]=sum/3} and B = {i | a[i+1]+a[i+2] +...+a[n-1]=sum/3}. You can store A and B in arrays which would be sorted. Now, what you are looking for is the number of pairs (i, j) such that i is from A and j is from B such that i <= j. What you could do is you is for each index i' in A for find the smallest j' in B such that  i' <= j' (this you could with binary search which takes O(log n) time). In this way all all indices j >= j' would be a solution so you add their count to the total count. This should give you the correct answer. So for the input

```
9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

you'd have that A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} and B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} (the array goes from 0 to 8). For index 1 in A you have that indices {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} that satisfy the problem, for 2 in A you have {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, etc. Again you have 7+6+5+4 + ... + 1 but instead of listing all possible indices you find their count using binary search in O(log n) time. So in total your algorithm would be O (n log n).

Here's an implementation of moreON's idea which further extends the binary search idea. Instead of restarting the binary search each iteration you start for the previously found index which yields O(n) amortized time in total

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int n;
long long sum, k;
int a[500010];

void solve()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d", a + i);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += a[i];

    if (sum % 3 != 0) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return;
    }
    k = sum / 3;
    vector<int> forward, backward;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-2; ++i) {
        sum += a[i];
        if (sum == k) {
            forward.push_back(i+1);
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
        sum += a[i];
        if (sum == k) {
            backward.push_back(i-1);
        }
    }
    reverse(backward.begin(), backward.end());

    int j = 0;
    int fn = forward.size();
    int bn = backward.size();
    long long ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fn; ++i) {
        while (j < bn && backward[j] < forward[i])
            j++;
        ans += bn-j;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}

int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: got my mistake. So, what can be an alternate approach to this then? Any hints?

Comment: @rohansingh binary search should work. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: You don't need to search all of B each time, simply scan from the previous j' - gives total runtime O(n) instead of O(nlogn). This is the detail I omitted from my answer, so I'm not convinced that I should have shared it here.

Comment: @moreON yea, you are right. I didn't give it more thought since after all the point of OP's question is **what is the flaw with his logic** and **not how does he solve the problem**.

Comment: @svs, so, I implemented your logic and I have posted it as part of the question. But I guess it's O(n^2) since `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) .... 1` is O(n^2) as well. Can you suggest me how do I make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that jumps to mind is that you want to find two split points that bound the array into sub arrays of exactly one-third the aggregate sum: that is, from 0 to p1, p1 to p2, and p2 to n-1. The second is that you want to handle the case where an element makes your sum overshoot the target value.  The third is that you want to handle zeroes in the array intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already worked out, first find the sum of the entire array.
You've said nothing about the potential for negative values. so I'll assume that they are possible.

Next, find every subarray which contains the first element* and has a sum equal to exactly one third of the total. We'll call these the left-subarrays. This should take you O(n). You'll need to record where all of these end.

Now do the same for every subarray which contains the last element*, also O(n), also record where they *start* (since they obviously all end at the same place). We'll call these the right-subarrays

Without giving everything away, now find the number of combinations of non-overlapping* left- and right- subarrays. (Because clearly the subarray between them also has the required sum of 1/3 of the total. If you do this part cleverly, it should be O(number of left-subarrrays + number of right-subarrays), this is, of course, still O(n).

I left out a detail in that last paragraph, yes, but I think for these type of challenges it's nice to leave you with a little of the challenge. And the entire thing should be possible in O(n)

*I should note that there is some variance on a few details based on whether the sum of the empty subarray is 0 or undefined for this problem. You'll need to carefully consider that as well. (Based on the example, I'd say the sum of the empty subarray is undefined, which means that non-overlapping also requires there to be a non-0 length gap)

Comment: so, I implemented your logic and I have posted it as part of the question. But I guess it's O(n^2) since (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) .... 1 is O(n^2) as well. Can you suggest me how do I make it more efficient?

Comment: You'd be better off storing a list of the positions you found rather than a boolean array of whether an index was a position you found.